# How to change just one title when multiple titles are present in mxd?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, mxd

I have an mxd with multiple titles and I'm trying to write a script that iterates a process that activates a layer, changes one of the titles, then exports it. I've got it all working except for changing the title. I can change the title but because there are multiple titles, it changes all of the titles to the same thing. Anyone know of a way to just target one of the titles within a mxd layout?

```
import arcpy

inputList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
bckGrndLyrs = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outputLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

for lyrs in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyrs.name in inputList:
        lyrs.visible = False
    elif lyrs.name in bckGrndLyrs:
        lyrs.visible = True  
    else:
        lyrs.visible = False

for inFC in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(inputList, "", df):
    if inFC.name in inputList:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Activating " + inFC.name + " Layer")
        inFC.visible = True

        for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
          mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
          for titleItem in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
            arcpy.AddMessage("...Changing title to " + inFC.name + " " + str(pageNum))
            titleItem.text = inFC.name 
          arcpy.AddMessage("......Refreshing Dataframe")
          arcpy.RefreshTOC()
          arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
          arcpy.AddMessage(".........Exporting " + inFC.name + " Page " + str(pageNum) + " as PDF")
          arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, outputLocation + " " + inFC.name + " " + str(pageNum) + ".pdf")
        inFC.visible = False

del mxd
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question and include a snippet of the code you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: Hey Midavalo, I added the script to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name your Text Elements (double-click on your title element, click the Size and Position tab, and in `Element Name` field, type in a unique name).

[image]

Then in your script, you can reference that unique name in order to modify the specific title text element.

```
for titleItem in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
    if titleItem.name == 'MyUniqueName':
        arcpy.AddMessage("...Changing title to " + inFC.name + " " + str(pageNum))
        titleItem.text = inFC.name
```

Then you're only modifying the title that matches the element name.

See [Text Element - ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/textelement-class.htm) for more info.

Comment: This is what I call "pseudo-dynamic text" and is an invaluable coding pattern when doing On Demand PDF Maps.